# Outlook shortcuts style toolbar in Qt

Tags: qt, outlook, toolbar, qtoolbar

Is there any way to create outloook shortcuts style toolbar in Qt? Should use normal toolbar and try to style it somehow (I have little idea how to achieve this)? Or does Qt provide builtin widget for this?

I am talking about toolbar like on this image: http://www.winsupersite.com/images/reviews/outlook2k2_01.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this can be done using Qt styling system and some options from the QToolBar itself. Now it looks just fine in our application.

Answer (score 0):

What toolbar are you refering to? If it is the one below the menu bar, use QToolBar combined with QToolButton and QAction.

For the box on the left side, check QToolBox. It looks similar.

Comment: I mean the left one, Outlook shortcuts.